# What is the largest number you can create with 0000 by moving only two sticks?

Tags: matches

Here's what I'm saying

[image: 0000]

Moving 2 sticks, what is the largest number that you can create?

Comment: You might want to add some more restrictions

Comment: Some answers use the argument that `1/0=infinity`. Unless you use the fact that `1/x --> INF` when `x --> 0`, that's not true. So... Do you consider that a valid answer?

Comment: Infinity is not a number.

Comment: and if you accept $1/0$ as ∞, then you have to accept it to be -∞ as well, which is, well, a *very small* number

Comment: Hello @bleh, did you make this puzzle yourself? Can I add it to my website? Of course, I will post it under your name - bleh (StackExchange).

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan Sure! I made it myself, inspired by other problems. You can use it freely.

Comment: At first make 11000, when stand two sticks, 11000・・. This is largest number.

Comment: Move the top and bottom sticks from the first 1 to make 111000, then interpret it in base Graham's number.

Comment: Sad that googol is not written in English as it is in French (gogol)...

Answer (score 97, accepted):

How about...

> Take the top and bottom sticks of the first zero, and place them upright on the bottom left, making $11^{11000}$?

If that's unrealistic...

> ... because the base is usually in bigger font, then $11000^{11}$ could work as well.

Comment: I think that's moving *four* sticks, not two.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος - no, it's moving two sticks; losing the top and bottom stick of the first 0 makes it an 11, and those two sticks are what gets moved to make the second, smaller 11 (of one stick each).

Comment: That means one stick makes 1 and two sticks also make 1. I think to make 1 number, it should be made by 2 sticks

Comment: I accounted for that. Exponents are in smaller font, so it's more aesthetically pleasing if you end up putting the tiny "11" on the top right instead.

Comment: @Megha thanks you made it crystal clear! ;)

Answer (score 95):

How about:

> [image]

As in,

> g<sub>900</sub>, the 900th term of the series used to generate [Graham's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number).

Comment: Not gonna get much bigger than that

Comment: This one is unimaginably larger than the top voted and accepted answer of 11^11000.
Even just trying to write g900 using only digits and exponents would not be possible to fit on a piece of paper that filled the visible universe.

Comment: And your answer inspired me to attempt to outdo you using the Busy Beaver function. See my answer below :)

Comment: The reason I didn't accept is because it was more of a function, not a value

Comment: You could even have made $g_{17130}$.

Comment: @bleh g900 is definitely a value, in the same way *Pi* or *11^11000* are values, it's just so large that it can only be expressed through recursion.

Comment: No, I dont think so mainly because you have to use a function to get to it. $11^11000$ is not a function-user because it only uses an operation instead of a function like G

Comment: Excellent idea, but mathematical notation is very case-sensitive: one wouldn’t ever write “G900” to mean g(900).  [8bittree’s answer below](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41926/4234) fixes this quibble.

Comment: @bleh You seem to differentiate between operations and functions. What is the difference?

Comment: It was an inferred limitation. :P

Comment: While I admit it could have been clearer that functions are not allowed, I think it's silly to not have understood that to begin with. Otherwise I'm going to declare a function called the A&%-hole function (A) that is simply the largest number on this page +1. Then all I have to do is move *one* stick on the first 0 to make it A000 (oh yeah, the function ignores any trailing numbers) and I will always win forever.

Comment: If this is a function, so is anything involving an exponent. It evaluates to a number, it's just a number so big you'd have to write it in this form because there isn't enough space in the visible universe to write down all its numerals.

Comment: @bleh How is $g$ a function? $g_{900}$ is a term in an existing series, just like how in some existing arbitrary series $a=\{2, 4, 6, 8, 10\}$, $a_2$ is $4$. You don't necessarily need to use a function to determine $a_2$'s value, nor do you need one to determine that of $g_{900}$ (though computing that is an entirely different matter).

Comment: @bleh as TNT mentions, there is no g function.  What there is, though, is a sequence, where g64 is Graham's number.

Answer (score 35):

Move the top and bottom matchsticks from the 3rd zero to make:

> [image: BB110]

Where the first two characters are B's thus: BB110
And BB refers to the [Busy Beaver Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver)
The Busy Beaver function is non-computable and therefor grows faster than any computable function such as exponentiation or the series to create Grahams Number.

The first few entries:

```
BB2 = 6 
BB3 = 21
BB4 = 107   
BB5 ≥ 47,176,870
BB6 > 7.4 × 10^36534 which is already greater than greenturtle3141's answer
BB12 > g1
```

which is already close enough to catching up to Graham's Sequence to pretty safely say that BB110 > g900 considering BB continues to ramp up faster than any computable function.

Comment: Radovan Gabarík had the same idea earlier, but the funny thing is, his answer is ridiculously small compared to this one.

Comment: Still a function....

Comment: You could be pedantic and define the Busy Beaver function to be B. In that case, your answer becomes B(B(110)), which is just silly.

Comment: This gets my vote (you could up it to $BB1717$ though). @JoelHarmon you have no sticks with which to do so, whereas $BB$ is already defined.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Could you clarify what you mean when you say I'm out of sticks? I've seen Busy Beaver abbreviated as both $BB$ and $B$. And while I agree that $BB$ is already defined, I'm much less certain it's uniquely defined. If it was, then the respondent wouldn't have needed to clarify that Busy Beaver was intended.

Comment: @JoelHarmon I *think* BB is common, but B would need to be defined, so you'd need sticks to define B (and that the answer only needs to say what BB is because many may never have heard of it before).

Comment: @bleh You asked for the largest number; not the largest numeral. This is a perfectly valid answer imho.

Comment: Also it's 88110, not BB110 :{

Comment: @bleh If you want to be pedantic about how characters are represented, none of these answers have any numbers in them, just a bunch of squares and lines made by matchsticks. Clearly it's not 88110 either since clearly '8' is two circles, not two squares.

Comment: But then, I guess there are no letters in this image http://www.romanblack.com/led_no/led_no09.jpg

Comment: Isn't the Busy Beaver function symbol "Σ" rather than "BB" anyway?

Comment: @oleslaw Many things have many representations. Sometimes multiplication is *, or a dot, or x, or sometimes entirely implicit. Here's an article written by a top quantum computer complexity theorist where he uses BB for the busy beaver function. http://www.scottaaronson.com/writings/bignumbers.html

Comment: A function related to Busy Beaver is the maximum shifts function S http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver#Maximum_shifts_function_S
. S800 is larger than BB110 and avoids the B's looking like 8's (slant the bar down slightly to avoid it looking like a 5).

Answer (score 34):

> Move the top and bottom stick of the first zero to create another 1, thus making 111000

Comment: Ugh.... too quick

Comment: And I was happy with my 9800...

Comment: @Chaotic I did [9900](/a/41891/12114).

Comment: And I thought I was clever with my E800.

Answer (score 22):

How about

> take the two bottom sticks from the leftmost zeros, break the end off of one and place it at the right hand side and place the other at the left hand side to make: $1171700!$ (or if the small 1 on the left is invalid make $771700!$
>
>  That's [$factorial(1171700)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial) (or $factorial(771700)$)
>
>  ...and given that $100000!=2.824229408×10^{456573}$ both of the above examples are pretty big.

For a less lateral-thinking solution

> - without breaking sticks, that is - one can make $7713170$ ($778170$ edit, credit @PaulGriffiths):

```
 _  _  _  _        _ _  _  _  _ 
| || || || |  -->   | ||_|| || |
|_||_||_||_|  -->   | ||_|| ||_|
```

Or for a smidgen more (due to @PaulGrffiths' observation on my previous attempt)

> $7717130$

```
 _  _  _  _        _ _  _  _  _ 
| || || || |  -->   | || ||_|| |
|_||_||_||_|  -->   | || ||_||_|
```

Comment: [I'm not sure that middle bit is true.](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) (though it is still very large)

Comment: @Will fine, I'll change it :)

Comment: Doesn't the 778817 solution have an extra stick?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 Oh my, oops! Changed it to a slightly smaller number - thanks!

Comment: Surely this is much bigger, at 7,713,170?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths - and a little more - thanks!

Comment: You don't have to break a matchstick; just stand it up on its end. Now you have $11000! = 3.1624624\times10^{39680}$ which is well over $11^{11000} = 2.087\times10^{11455}$

Comment: @EngineerToast If they were *match*sticks

Comment: Argh, I mistyped. You can still stand a sick on end, though. The high def drawing by OP seems to show them as fairly straight. Actually, sticks would be easier because they would be stiff enough to push into the dirt and stand on their own.

Comment: 1,171,700 seems larger than 771,780.

Answer (score 14):

Expanding on greenturtle3141's answer:

> Using [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) notation we can express
>  $$^{11000}11$$
>  which is
>  $\underbrace{11^{11^{...^{11}}}}_{11000\mbox{~times}}$

Looking at [the examples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration#Examples), even the number of digits of this number will be insanely high.

Comment: this is very clear, the largest one, it should have been accepted, i think it's not even computable?

Comment: @garg10may , Petr Pudlák, this is NOT computable with a normal computer. My computer is over-average and to calculate $5_{11}$ took 3 seconds, $9_{11}$ took to long (Java...) - after a minute I terminated it. $5_{11} =$ I can't paste the number here, beacuse it has cca 14000 digits! I'm allowed 600....

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek It can't be computed even with supercomputer.

Comment: @garg10may Maybe I could estimate the number of digits ofthe number of digits ofthe number of digits ofthe number of digits of the number :)

Comment: @garg10may I got it! The number of digits of the number has 10500 (plus minus 200) digits! Well, didn't get farther than that with my Java Super-Skills :)

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek say if instead of 11 it was 10, then 10^10 has 100 digits.  10^10^10 has 1000 digits. 10^10^10^10 has 10,000 digits, we have done just 4 iterations. Similarly with 11000 iterations it would be 1 after it 11000 zeros and whatever that number is called, that many digits. I don't know how you got 10500 (plus minus 200), these few digits would be just with 4 iterations. Therefore I say not computable.

Comment: @garg10may That's the number of digits of the number of digits of the number. Double-digited.

Comment: @garg10may technically, all natural numbers are computable.  What's not computable are certain real numbers.  Computable doesn't refer to whether or not physical computers can 'compute' it, but rather whether a Turing machine can 'theoretically compute' it.

Answer (score 13):

> 9900
> Here are the sticks on their initial positions:
>
> ```
> +--------+ +--------+ +--------+ +--------+
> |        | |        | |        | |        |
> |        | |        | |        | |        |
> |        | |        | |        | |        |
> +        + +        + +        + +        +
> |        | |        | |        | |        |
> |        | |        | |        | |        |
> |        | |        | |        | |        |
> +--------+ +--------+ +--------+ +--------+
> ```
>
> Just flip two, and...
>
> ```
> +--------+ +--------+ +--------+ +--------+
> |        | |        | |        | |        |
> |        | |        | |        | |        |
> |        | |        | |        | |        |
> +--------+ +--------+ +        + +        +
>          |          | |        | |        |
>          |          | |        | |        |
>          |          | |        | |        |
> +--------+ +--------+ +--------+ +--------+
> ```

Comment: what about 111000 ? Remove top and bottom from first 0, you get 11000, then use the 2 sticks to create another 1 to put in front.

Comment: This was the already the first answe (Jon Mark Perry's below).

Comment: @z100 Nope. The answer you specify is invalid, because infinity is a mathematical concept, not a number.

Comment: Sorry, BlueFire's (Jon just edited).

Comment: @z100 revering now.......

Answer (score 11):

> Take the top and bottom of the first 0 and place around the remaining matches to form the absolute value function. Then we have $|\dfrac{1}{000}|=\infty$.

Comment: I'll be "that guy" ... not technically true ... 1/0 is not infinity, it's just undefined

Comment: mathmo's write $\lim\limits_{x\to0^+}\dfrac1x=\infty$, so it is. $\lim\limits_{x\to0^-}\dfrac1x=-\infty$ on the other hand

Comment: infinity is not a number, its a mathematical concept

Comment: Also, I think that the slash should look like a slash, not $|$.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: _"so it is"_ no because you just showed a different thing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit; i guess, most people just accept the first example without questioning stuff too deeply i suppose

Comment: Prove that infinity is a number.

Comment: before i can, i need to know your definition of a number and your definition of infinity; @numberknot

Comment: Number:an arithmetical value, expressed by a word, symbol, or figure, representing a particular quantity and used in counting and making calculations.

Comment: like infinity?@numberknot

Comment: @JonMarkPerry: No, infinity is not a quantity.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)  = L \nRightarrow f(c) = L$

Comment: @ChrisBurt-Brown 0/0 is undefined. 1/0 is +infinity.

Comment: $1/0 = \infty$ if we are in the extended complex plane.
Of course one could argue that the elements of the extend complex plane are not numbers, 
and/or that they are not ordered, and thus $\infty$ is not the largest of them (though it is in magnitude)

Comment: I don't see how you can do this without moving more than two sticks.

Comment: @polkovnikov If you could please provide the proof showing that the limit for `x -> 0^-` for 1/x is infinity (so how do I get latex to work here?) and not negative infinity I'd be much obliged. I'll even let you publish that break through paper first if you want to.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph You have corrected me wrongly :) [1/0 is not +infinity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144526/is-it-wrong-to-tell-children-that-1-0-nan-is-incorrect-and-should-be-%e2%88%9e).

Comment: @Oxinabox: I'd argue it's acceptable to use the extended complex plane as long as you can convey that while moving only two sticks

Comment: @ChrisBurt-Brown I totally forgot that most of `puzzling` readers are kids. Or did you mean something else by linking a question "if it's okay to tell kids $1/0=\infty$"?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, $\infty$ of the projective numbers is a quantity. And so is the $\pm \infty$ of the extended reals. (and cardinal numbers like $\aleph_0$, although that's a mostly unrelated topic)

Comment: I will grant, however, that whatever vague, formless notion of infinity the people who say "infinity is just a concept" have in mind is probably not a number.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I am just providing a citation for 1/0 ≠ ∞ and that was the first one to come up, I am sure a little hunting around math.SE can provide a better link

Answer (score 10):

Inspired by [MooseBoys](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41888/16838):

> `_  _  _  _       _     _  _ 
> | || || || | --> | || || || |
> |_||_||_||_|     |_|| ||_||_|
>                   _|`
>
>
> g1100 is quite a bit greater than g900. Not sure that it's greater than [BB110](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41914/16838), though.

Comment: It's way smaller than BB110, trust me...

Answer (score 9):

I'm new here but couldn't resist this one. How about

> Move the bottom sticks of the first two numbers up to the middle row which gives AA00 which is hexadecimal for 43520

**EDIT**

Can even go a little further with this one and

> Move the two right sticks from the first 0 to the middle row of the middle two 0s giving C880 which is hex for 51328

Comment: C0001 is larger.

Comment: If you're going to change the numerical base, why stop at hexadecimal? C0001 in base 17 is bigger. C0001 in base G900 is even bigger. You can trivially beat any other answer by saying your >10 number is in base (their number).

Comment: I like that even more!

Answer (score 8):

[image]

If you count this as $900!$ (900 factorial) then it is

$6752680220964584158387906136180081422426942786958938431219826870368509164318041$$696913244695269830379422601037057867290859319834769988692859190650103158765184$$697675968111260952478709384800442863618689339527278445063035408024321764665802$$469665906595179375722352022923557754865383368110217097389374605464912641590914$$315017286072115668581065575923001145013299217645498322753869634011261044702900$$233700488787726638770458607729358543315161251880014776446118268082286709278669$$498283183864180099749981933920657941532564974848626523391891108711459244089659$$406267591429492581671986217837467927209263752478693903629003592427178225373805$$988693392344787776958300301670536333903141306915583751852476107834205263547563$$211316961877454927570148010693336299000373258937059355732529943473445929586672$$898874079417465439147992600084884668670872973671320728520371273220127241083083$$691305263536508288872517163608158715160346829110675464039823214667362737089593$$409077782882754955423243619046482799868392717924602991944325102646445233793959$$919852829782859112268996062036123824831315807164339584840504726141268003987773$$376184987444732386791171263002317174596827846578055856806703501388527508029213$$736049187516494772446422169353375503530006535006513749083203952338296374702618$$565305033183238099184484256075092354377518858209648747695025441836519899967468$$441728626544278665159440478162294690187916638293071419690822746013302760581786$$487737771219314213762543035371844826939073261577664528319882860291768022404108$$899389261050680219591724783890010691069805703037919057105760584932311330863445$$200817988116561644976764835416122506696796129760969874273792338939161520744115$$231939284568767331189924708532770342186297287164449540957225998556321547148208$$332565323177711327132657997031075560497396970894947737425497448029465242702243$$670538018406400885345721451851527098556319541299314527405768863444881244944580$$061763116276824312560642484470937202214990846357225491265490776344575854398099$$914912299810437896562678189865522144326360140515207319970658508028873504020541$$737127725309624320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000$$000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000$$000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000$$0000000$

With number of trailing 0s $= 224$ and total number of digits $= 2270$

Answer (score 6):

Assuming calculator font only with no superscript or letters or other formatting changes, but still allowing the addition of numbers:

> ```
>  _  _  _  _             _  _  _  _ 
> | || || || |    ->    || || || || |
> |_||_||_||_|          |  ||_||_||_|
> ```
>
> Thus 17000

Answer (score 6):

Answer:

> gogol, which is French for [Googol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googol) ($10^{100}$)

Why:

> `_  _  _  _       _  _  _  _ 
> | || || || | --> |  | ||  | | |
> |_||_||_||_|     |_||_||_||_| |`

Answer (score 5):

Move the two horizontal bars of the first 0 to make a slash:

> 11/000

which evaluates to infinity!

Comment: or 011/00 or 0011/0.

Comment: As written, I think it's indeterminate, not infinity.

Comment: 0/0 is indeterminate

Comment: sigh, how can you evaluate infinity considering it has no value...

Comment: @Gnubie 1/+0 goes to positive infinity. 1/-0 goes to negative infinity. 1/0 is indeterminate. All this applies only when it's part of a limit. Otherwise, it is undefined.$\frac{1}{0}=x\Rightarrow1=0x$ and there is no value for $x$ where this is true, not even "infinity" which is technically not even a number.

Comment: Unless this is utilizing Wheel Theory...

Answer (score 5):

```
 _  _  _  _          _  _  _  _   
| || || || |  -->   |_||_|| || |
|_||_||_||_|  -->   |_||_|  ||_|
```

i.e.

> BB70, the 70th [Busy Beaver number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_beaver), which is uncomputable, most likely even independent from ZFC and thus bigger than any other natural number mentioned so far.

Comment: Except the answer is indistinguishable from 8870.

Answer (score 4):

```
 _  _  _  _          _  _  _  _   
| || || || |  -->   |_||_|| || |
|_||_||_||_|  -->   | | _||_||_|
```

That is, in the spirit of the Graham and Busy Beaver answers, A(900) where A is the one-argument version of the [Ackermann Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function).

I'm pretty sure this loses to the BB answer, but I'm less certain about Graham's. I just thought Ackermann could use some love, too. At the very least this is also an unimaginably large number.

Comment: I don't see how you can have accomplished this by only moving two sticks. It looks like you *added* a stick (the bottom of the leftmost zero moves up to make the A; one move ... the lower left of the second zero rotates 90˚ to make the 9; second move ... now where did the crosspiece come from to turn the third zero into an eight?). You can still have A(900) though :)

Answer (score 3):

Late answer but here's one for fans of out of the box thinking:

> Pick up two sticks, take a walk down to the beach with someone you love, draw this in the sand

> [image]

> and define this symbol to represent a number larger than any ever conceived.  That's right, it gets bigger the more you think about it. By definition x < ♡ is true for all x. Yes even that one. Now that's a big heart. Who could love you more than that?

Comment: nice try, +1 for making hearts out of ms paint strokes

Answer (score 2):

Theres a lot of good answers but I though this one is worth mentioning as it is the only one I can see that wouldn't result in badly justified or sized numbers.

> Move the lower left of the first two digits up to be the middle horizontal bar giving 9900

Comment: _"It's over 9000!"_

Answer (score 2):

Take the bottom stick from each of the first two digits, giving

> `_  _  _  _       _  _  _  _ 
> | || || || | --> | || || || |
> |_||_||_||_|     | || ||_||_|`

i.e.

> 171700 .

Then

> rotate them to make an 11, and raise this to the power 171700:
>
>     `_  _  _  _ 
>    | || || || |
>    | || ||_||_|
> | |`

i.e.

> $11^{171700}$.

This is

> $1.33 * 10^{178807}$

to 3 significant figures.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

> [image: Big Number]

Which is read as:

> $$9^{{1717}^6}$$

That is rougly:

> [A number with 24450093851501172475 decimal digits](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9%5E1717%5E6).

Comment: They should be the same size at least if you're going to do that

Comment: @bleh doesn't say that anywhere in the question, seems readable enough to me. Though h34's answer beats it anyways, so somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: But if the size of the 1 is an issue, then not a problem. Try the new version out for size, much larger value.

Answer (score 1):

```
88110

Here are the sticks on their initial positions:

+--------+ +--------+ +--------+ +--------+
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|        | |        | |        | |        |
+        + +        + +        + +        +
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|        | |        | |        | |        |
+--------+ +--------+ +--------+ +--------+
Just flip two, and...
+--------+ +--------+ +        + +--------+
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|        | |        | |        | |        |
+--------+ +--------+ +        + +        +
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|        | |        | |        | |        |
|        | |        | |        | |        |
+--------+ +--------+ +        + +--------+
```

Answer (score 0):

> Move two sticks to make 1/0 (can be infinite). I change the 0 into a C in the process.
>
>
>              1
>              _
>            000C

Comment: The number is not as big as you expect.

Comment: What do you mean by `C`? The speed of light? An hexadecimal 12? Either case, if `C` is dividing the number, then you have a *small* number, not a big one

Comment: @Barranka regardless of what C is, it's still 0C which is 0. I needed to find a way to make the denominator stay 0 when I removed some sticks so I made a C.

Comment: @TonyRuth Not necessarily... if it's `000C` hexadecimal, it's 12, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

> Take the right hand side 2 of the last two zero making them into two CC. Then create two 1 like this:
> 1100CC which is 1100*C squared where C is the speed of light 
> (as in E=MC squared)
> 1100 * 299792458 * 299792458 = 98,863,069,661,049,940,400  
> ie. 98 quintillion give or take a few quadrillion

Comment: It is not a number but a quantity.

Comment: You're moving 4 matches, and you're only allowed to move 2.

Answer (score 0):

> 110,001

can be made as follows:

`_   _   _`   
`| | | | | | | | |`
`| | |_| |_| |_| |`

Comment: Another case of [an edit after an auto flag yielding a down vote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/276269/community-should-not-autodownvote-low-quality-autoflags-cleared-by-edits).