# Unexpectedly Difficult Matchstick Problem

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, matches

The words say:

听说只有智商高达200的人才有办法打出来 (only people with 200 iq can solve this).

只移动1根火柴让算式成立 (move only one match to satisfy the equation)

note: it is not my puzzle and i do not know the solution

[image]

Comment: welcome to puzzling se

Comment: Are we allowed to rot13(cynpr n zngpu bire gur rdhnyf fvta ng na natyr gb znxr gur "qbrf abg rdhny" fvta)? If so, there are several solutions.

Comment: @LannyStrack if that were the case, this would be a very dull puzzle. Not sure if there are any actual solutions besides that, working on it

Comment: @OliverNi - It is not unheard of to have a trick question whose answer is dull (once you know the trick).

Comment: @LannyStrack That is definitely true. I hope there is an actual solution though, if not, that would be sad

Comment: Congratulations! The puzzle has two nice answers. There is a single observation which can lead to either of the two solutions. In my opinion the result should be an equation, not an inequality, if the English translation is precise.

Comment: If you tried to solve this on an internet site with cookies then it tells advertisers you are someone who has a) time to waste b) you are a problem solver rather than a manager or something, therefore probably earning enough c) you are motivated by proving your intelligence.  The correct answer therefore depends on what kind of ads you want to pop up everywhere when browsing the web.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> Remove the top left match of "9". Then the "9" becomes a "3". Place the removed match horizontally before "3". Then, it becomes "-3".
>  So, our equation becomes
>  -3+5=2

Comment: I like that better than my answer.

Comment: Nice! how did i not see that??

Comment: Congratulations @Sid. 200 IQ!

Comment: My solution was to take that one and put it over the equal sign, changing it to "not equal," but I like yours better.

Answer (score 36):

Here's a rather "basic" answer:

> Move the top-right vertical match in the 2 to the top-left vertical position so that the right hand side forms an 'E'.
>  The equation then becomes 9 + 5 = E, where E is 14 in the hexadecimal number system. 9 and 5 are represented the same in both decimal and hexadecimal, so the left hand side of the equation is unchanged.

Comment: Found the computer nerd :-)

Comment: Definitely a +1 from me mainly because [my first answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/41895/29729) on the site also involved matches and a sneaky abuse of hex :)

Answer (score 30):

You can also

> remove the vertical match from the plus sign and place it slanted over the equals sign to get $9-5\neq2$.

Comment: the question does say "satisfy the _equation_"

Comment: The translation provided with the question does say "equation", but Google Translate says "算式" is "formula", so, if this is correct, I would say this answer qualifies.

Answer (score 17):

I am not sure if this is what the puzzle creator has in mind, but if you:

> discard the match in the upper left (e.g., "moving" it by striking it so that it lights and then burns up), and then rotate yourself behind the puzzle looking at it upside down (equivalent to flipping the puzzle around an imaginary x-axis), it reads 3+2=5.

Comment: rot13(Ybbxvat ng vg "sebz oruvaq" [fhpu nf sebz gur obggbz bs n tynff gnoyr] jba'g jbex orpnhfr gur 3 orpbzrf na R. Ohg hfvat n zveebe fubhyq jbex)

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - that is not what I wrote. Read the full answer.

Comment: wouldn't the 3 be backwards?

Comment: @SwissFrank - no. rotate it 180 degrees on the x-axis. still forwards.

Answer (score 11):

Another [lateral-thinking] option is

> Tilt the upper match of the equals sign, making it into a greater than sign

Comment: You beat me to it! This was the solution I saw.

Comment: The question does say "satisfy the *equation*".

Comment: I'm probably going to regret asking this, but my mind is blanking. What's it called if you're not using "="? i.e. "9+5 > 2" ....... Is that a statement? or formula? What if you moved the left-top of the 9 to get "3+5 >= 2" (use imagination for >= as one sign please) - is that an equation? or a statement? (or whatever word I can't think of..)

Comment: @TCooper "inequality", although the starting "statement" is not already an inequality.

Answer (score 2):

> I’m thinking hexadecimal here.  Therefore 9+5=E, in Base16.  >!One matchstick from 2 to E.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! I'm afraid somebody already beat you to this answer: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/98050/31839

Comment: That’s cool, just wanted to participate.  My first time here in this particular community.

Comment: @JoeyGodwin  please "spoilerize" any answer you post in this group.  See the "help" section for formatting tips

Answer (score 1):

I saw this once and a solution I saw was

> Remove a match from the 9 to make it a 3. Then put that extra match over the equals sign to make a not equals sign (≠)

Comment: Welcome to [puzzling.se]! This answer has already been given: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/98042/11110